# Angular with exif-js only on production mode not work correctly

Tags: angular, exif-js

When I make an **ng serve** on  my project it's work just fine. But when I run **ng build --prod --base-href** then some problems connected with **exif-js** will show up.

```
main-es2015.4f373a513488bb1e69c9.js:40745 ERROR ReferenceError: n is not defined
    at getStringFromDB (main-es2015.4f373a513488bb1e69c9.js:126856)
    at readEXIFData (main-es2015.4f373a513488bb1e69c9.js:126863)
    at findEXIFinJPEG (main-es2015.4f373a513488bb1e69c9.js:126564)
    at handleBinaryFile (main-es2015.4f373a513488bb1e69c9.js:126485)
    at getImageData (main-es2015.4f373a513488bb1e69c9.js:126501)
    at Function.push../node_modules/exif-js/exif.js.EXIF.getData (main-es2015.4f373a513488bb1e69c9.js:127098)
    at ImagesLoadingService.loadExif (main-es2015.4f373a513488bb1e69c9.js:153715)
    at HTMLImageElement.img.onload [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYload] (main-es2015.4f373a513488bb1e69c9.js:153689)
    at HTMLImageElement.wrapFn (polyfills-es2015.c96fb5427ba53ad92441.js:1201)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills-es2015.c96fb5427ba53ad92441.js:403)
```

I know the error reason is **some variable is not defined** but why on **ng serve** it's work correctly?

**SOLVED**

I find problem in **exif.js** file:

```
    function getStringFromDB(buffer, start, length) {
        var outstr = "";
        for (let n = start; n < start+length; n++) { // I add let before n variable and now it's work just fine on prod build
            outstr += String.fromCharCode(buffer.getUint8(n));
        }
        return outstr;
    }
```

I build project in **ng build --prod --base-href --optimization=false** to find the problem place. On **Firefox** I get **diffrent error description** so I can't find specific place of code. Only on **Chrome** I get more specific info about that and I can solve my probem. I hope someone else this will help too :)

Comment: How are you importing the library?

Comment: Well i'ts strange but I solved problem. Problem was in exif.js file

Comment: It is better to add the solution description as an answer and accept it. Then others will find the solution more easily.

Comment: I add my solution as comment but I can't accept it becouse it is my own question :)

Comment: You need to have reputation 15+ to be able to accept answer to your own question and wait 48 hours: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info about that

Comment: Well there is one extra rule I must have wait 2 days to vote on my own answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find problem in **exif.js** file:

```
    function getStringFromDB(buffer, start, length) {
        var outstr = "";
        for (let n = start; n < start+length; n++) { // I add let before n variable and now it's work just fine on prod build
            outstr += String.fromCharCode(buffer.getUint8(n));
        }
        return outstr;
    }
```

I build project in **ng build --prod --base-href --optimization=false** to find the problem place. On **Firefox** I get **diffrent error description** so I can't find specific place of code. Only on **Chrome** I get more specific info about that and I can solve my probem. I hope someone else this will help too :)